# unzip file silently vbscript

Tags: vbscript, unzip

I found online script that basically unzip every .zip archive in a given path.

```
sub UnzipAll(path)

set folder = fso.GetFolder(path)

for each file in folder.files

    if (fso.GetExtensionName(file.path)) = "zip" then

        set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

        objshell.NameSpace(path).CopyHere objshell.NameSpace(file.path).Items

        file.delete

    end if

next

end sub
```

This is actually working, but the problem is that I want to unzip **"silently"** (silently means that I don't want any kind of message from the system when unzipping, like "do you want to overwrite?" ect.).

I've searched a lot on google and I found that you just need to add a few flags on the "CopyHere" method, like this:

```
objshell.NameSpace(path).CopyHere objshell.NameSpace(file.path).Items, *FLAGHERE*
```

But the problem is right here. The flags would normally work, but they are completely ignored when unzipping a .zip archive.

So I searched for a workaround, but I didn't find anything helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do it by myself. Basically you want to unzip 1 file per time and not everyone togheter, and before copying it you just check if it already exists, and evenutally delete it:

```
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


sub estrai(percorso)

set cartella = fso.GetFolder(percorso)

for each file in cartella.files


    if fso.GetExtensionName(file.path) = "zip" then


        set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

        set destinazione = objShell.NameSpace(percorso)

        set zip_content = objShell.NameSpace(file.path).Items   

        for i = 0 to zip_content.count-1

            'msgbox fso.Buildpath(percorso,zip_content.item(i).name)+"."+fso.getExtensionName(zip_content.item(i).path)

            if (fso.FileExists(fso.Buildpath(percorso,zip_content.item(i).name)+"."+fso.getExtensionName(zip_content.item(i).path))) then

                'msgbox "il file esiste, ora lo cancello"
                fso.DeleteFile(fso.Buildpath(percorso,zip_content.item(i).name)+"."+fso.getExtensionName(zip_content.item(i).path))

            end if

            destinazione.copyHere(zip_content.item(i))

        next        

        file.Delete

    end if

next

'for each sottocartella in cartella.subfolders
'   call estrai(folder.path)
'next

end sub

call estrai("C:\Documents and Settings\Mattia\Desktop\prova")
```